# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'salao.Users' doesn't exist

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sequelize-js

Bom dia, Estou me deparando com o seguinte problema

```
Executing (default): INSERT INTO `Users` (`id`,`name`,`email`,`avatar`,`password_hash`,`provider`,`createdAt`,`updatedAt`) VALUES (DEFAULT,?,?,?,?,?,?,?);
(node:3215) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SequelizeDatabaseError: Table 'salao.Users' doesn't exist
```

como podemos ver ele esta tentando inserir em uma tabela chamada "Users", o problema é que no BD a table se chama "users" (com a inicial minúscula). Estou utilizando o MySql, NodeJs e Sequelize.

Answer (score 1):

O recomendado é o uso da opção `tableName` ao declarar o seu Model.

```
sequelize.define('users', { 
  id: Sequelize.INTEGER,
  name: Sequelize.STRING,
  ...
}, {
   tableName: 'users'
});
```

Comment: Essa solução de usar o tableName funcionou perfeitamente pra mim. em 23/12/2020.

Answer (score 0):

No model de sua tabela, após listar todos os campos, adicione:

```
adicionefreezeTableName: true
```